# Unable to determine why eigenvalue results are different between Julia and Python for specific case

Tags: python, numpy, julia, eigenvalue

I'm using Julia to do some linear algebra calculations but it gave me negative eigenvalues when I know the matrix is positive definite.

I'm fairly new to Julia so is there some reason the Julia code below would have such different behavior than the corresponding python code?  Could it be the `abs` function?  At this point I'm at a loss.

The Julia code is:

```
using LinearAlgebra

time = collect(range(0.0, 10.0, length=400)) 
H = 0.8
N = length(time)
C_N = Matrix{Float32}(undef,N,N)
for i in 1:N
    for j in 1:N 
        ti,tj = time[i], time[j]
        C_N[i,j] = 0.5*(ti^(2*H)+tj^(2*H) - abs(ti-tj)^(2*H))
    end         
end
Decomposition = eigen(C_N)
eigen_vals = Decomposition.values
has_negative = any(x -> x < 0.0, eigen_vals)
if has_negative
    @show "Has Negative eigenvalue"
else
    @show "Only positive eigenvalues"
end
has_negative
```

The output is:

```bash
"Has Negative eigenvalue" = "Has Negative eigenvalue"
```

The corresponding python code is:

```py
import numpy as np
H = 0.8
N =400
time = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,num=N)
C_N = np.zeros((N,N))
print(time.shape)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        ti,tj = time[i],time[j]
        C_N[i,j] = 0.5*(ti**(2*H)+tj**(2*H) - np.abs(ti-tj)**(2*H))

w, V = np.linalg.eig(C_N)
neg_mask = w < 0.0
if np.any(neg_mask):
    print("Negative eigenvalue found")
else:
    print("Only positive eigenvalues")
```

which outputs:

```bash
"Only positive eigenvalues"
```

For reference I am using Julia v"1.8.2".

Answer (score 1):

It was the `Float32` which led to numerical errors.  Changing to `Float64` fixed it.  I'll keep the question up for posterity.